# How does the &-bitwise operator work?

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

How does this & (ampersand) bit-wise operator work?

```
$bcast = ip2long("192.168.178.255");
$smask = ip2long("255.255.255.0");
$nmask = $bcast & $smask;
echo long2ip($nmask); // Will give 192.168.178.0
```

Does it compare each several bit? I understand most of the magic in this snippet is done by `long2ip()`, but how does `$nmask` give the right value?

Edit: To clarify..
`$bcast` returns '3232281343'
`$smask` returns '3232281088'

1) Will the &-operator automagically turn this to their binary number?
2) As per my comment to AbraCadaver; what are some use cases where you want to use the bitwise operator?

Comment: `1 & 1 = 1`. `0 & 0 = 0`. `1 & 0 = 0`. `0 & 1= 0`. That's how. What happens is that both numbers have binary representation. Then what happens is that you apply this simple boolean operator on each bit of the two numbers and get the result.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: Offtopic - @vascowhite - your "about" is simply amazing, kind of applies to this question as well I'm afraid :/

Comment: @N.B. Thanks, it applies far too often I'm afraid :(

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with being lazy? I've already read the documentation, since I asked "does it compare each several bit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compares each bit of the binary of the long and where both bits are `1` the result is `1`, otherwise the result is `0`.  So for example:

first octet:

```
192    = 11000000
255    = 11111111
result = 11000000 = 192
```

last octet:

```
255    = 11111111
0      = 00000000
result = 00000000 = 0
```

Comment: Besides the above example, when would you use this operation? Since it's like an 'all or nothing' kind of thing..